# Gate Define not working for other users except whose role_id is 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization, laravel-gate

The Below code in middleware is working fine when user has role_id 1, When I did the dd on role->permissions I get then the response is array.

But on this middleware line

```
if (in_array($role->permissions, $permission)) {
```

I get this error for all other users whose role_id is different

in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, string given where array was passed

My Roles Model has

```
protected $casts = [
        'permissions' => 'array',
    ];
```

My User Model has

```
protected function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Roles::class, 'id', 'role_id');
    }
```

My web Middlewaregroup has

```
\App\Http\Middleware\RolePermissionCheck::class,
```

My Meddlware has

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;


class RolePermissionCheck
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!empty(Auth::user()->role_id)) {
            $role = Auth::user()->role;

            Gate::before(
                function () {
                    if (Auth::user()->role_id === 1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            );
            // dd($role->permissions);
            foreach ($role->permissions as $permission) {
                Gate::define(
                    $permission,
                    function ($role) use ($permission) {
                        if (in_array($role->permissions, $permission)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, the problem will be in Foreach loop for Gate defining.
In first itteration of loop (based on your sample array) you would have `$action = 0` and `$roles = 'admin_role_manage'`. So the name of gate would be `0`. So of course, then `@can('admin_role_manage')` is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mark my answer as correct as user [Autista_z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4771277/autista-z) told you the fix, I am going to share something to have a better code, really simple and "Laravel way" stuff to do.

As user [Autista_z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4771277/autista-z) said: "the problem will be in `foreach` loop for `Gate` defining. In first iteration of loop (based on your sample array) you would have `$action = 0` and `$roles = 'admin_role_manage'`. So the name of gate would be `0`. So of course, then `@can('admin_role_manage')` is `false`".

---

So, You are setting up or getting a lot of stuff that is not needed, or worded other way, you can have a clearer code (at least for your `Middleware` class).

If you know (maybe you don't), you can [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) models properties to a type you want, so instead of doing `json_decode($user_role->permissions)` you can simply do `foreach ($user_role->permissions as $role)`, but before you do so you need to cast it.

So your model would have a property `$casts` as this:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'permissions' => 'array',
];
```

This will allow you to do `$model->permissions = ['role_1', 'role_2', ...];` without the need of doing `$model->permissions = json_encode(['role_1', 'role_2', ...]);` (and also this is the Laravel way of handling this).

So your middleware would end like:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Roles;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class RolePermissionCheck
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($role = Auth::user()->role)) {
            Gate::before(
                function (User $user) {
                    if ($user->role_id === '1') {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            );

            foreach ($role->permissions as $permission) {
                Gate::define(
                    $permission,
                    function ($role) use ($permission) {
                        if (in_array($permission, $role->permissions)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

See that I have changed the wording of `$role->permissions as $roles` to `$role->permissions as $permission`, your `role` could be "Writer" and your permissions are `newsletter_manage`, `brand_logos`, `quote_manage`, and more. So this are not roles but permissions.

Also have in mind that I think you can even have better code for the `foreach/define` part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I had done the same as above but have a small issue checked with both role_id, role and !empty but no change  /
if (!empty($role = Auth::user()->role_id))  /
**ErrorException**  /
Attempt to read property "role" on null

Comment: It is passing a null array

Comment: I had done like this    /       if (!empty(Auth::user()->role_id)) { 
$role = Auth::user()->role_id;       /        it is working but got other issue after login
/                  Attempt to read property "permissions" on int       /         on foreach ($role->permissions as $permission) {

Comment: When I am performing dd on role_id of user I receive the response only 1 not "1" do this has some to do with the permissions

Comment: I had added protected $cast in roles model

Comment: Do you have a relation for `role_id` ? If you do, can you share that one line of code here ?

Comment: Roles Model

protected $fillable = [
        'role_name',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'permissions' => 'array',
    ];

Comment: Users Model

protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'role_id',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

  
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasOne(Roles::class);
    }

Comment: so, `roles` relation is your problem, if you have a `hasOne` relation hence 1 to 1 relation, you have to name your relation as singular, because you are getting one thing, not multiple, so `roles` should be named `role`, and then my code will work for you. See that in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) (when singular and when plural). Try it with singular and tell me if it works now. Same for your `Roles` class. All clases must be **singular**, because you always have 1 entity in your model, if you have a `many` relation, that is other stuff.

Comment: So your classes must always be singular, `Role`, `User`, etc.

Comment: Sorry if my comments are harsh, take them as constructive not destructive please

Comment: Thanks, Brother, for the reply I will try it out and Let you know  
Your Comments are not harsh

Comment: Had done changes as you asked got some errors, so I had done some modification below is the Models and Middleware created

Comment: what are the new errors ? Update your question's codes with the new code.

Comment: My Answer Post was deleted So, I am updating my Post again, so please check the post again

Comment: I am not able to post the changes please check the link below.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-7D_R93gCkwd5tBZB4UTs2bKfURr_aeBP_Yyy-nKhUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't post the changes, update your question with new changes. What is the error now ?

Comment: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, string given in `if (in_array($role->permissions, $permission))`

Comment: that is saying that you did not write `$casts` to your model class, so it is still being a string (json).

Comment: `protected $casts = [
        'permissions' => 'array',
    ];`

Comment: When I perform dd on `$role->permissions` it returns the array as in the above array in my question.

Comment: For more details please check out my question again I had updated It
@matiaslauriti

Comment: Sorry, I read it again and it is saying that `$permission` that comes from `$role->permissions as $permission`, is a string instead of an array. Can you `dd($premission)` to see what it is and what it has ?

Comment: When I do `dd($permission)` inside foreach then the resopnse is 1st array only.

Comment: `dd($role->permissions)' response `array:2 [▼
  0 => "menus_manage"
  1 => "admin_role_manage"
]` and when `dd($permission)` resopnse is `"menus_manage"`.

Comment: When I perform echo without dd on permissions response is `menus_manage
admin_role_manage` with break between menu_manage & admin_role_manage

Comment: I have updated my answer, see that we were using `in_array` wrongly, we do not have to do `in_array($role->permissions, $permission)`, we had to do `in_array($permission, $role->permissions)`, now it should work for you.

Comment: After changing that I am getting this error `in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, null given` on `if (in_array($permission, $role->permissions)) {`

Comment: After that error when I echo and dd on `$role->permissions` & `$permission` inside `if ( in_array($permission, $role->permissions)) {` by replacing with `if (is_array($role->permissions) && in_array($permission, $role->permissions)) {` to check the output the responce is null and empty on `$role->permissions` where as the response on `$permission` is the first array i.e., `menus_manage`

Comment: I have no idea now, it is weird and this is really long now. Sorry

Comment: It is okay no problem is there any other way around to fix it or any other method that you had implemented It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I made some changes and now the code is working fine. If there are any suggestions to make is better please let me know. I would appreciate it.
`if (isset($permission[$role->permissions])) {return true;} else { return false;}`

I had to remove the in_array and changed it to isset & it worked. true and false are just for the understanding purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @matiaslauriti, for your support I Appreciate your efforts. If there are any upgrades in the codes please let me know.

Comment: but `$permission[$role->permissions]` makes no sense, you are telling a string to see in position `array` -> `$role->permissions` to see if it exists ?

Comment: How can we make is better, Any suggestions.